# Como descobrir se um diretório está vazio pelo terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Eu enviei uns arquivos, via ftp, para colocar minha aplicação em produção.

Por algum erro ocorrido na aplicação, percebi que alguns arquivos estavam faltando. Quando dei um `ls` percebi que algumas pastas estavam vazias, mas não tenho como entrar em uma por uma para conferir.

Como listar pastar vazias no `Linux` ? Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso pelo terminal?

Comment: Tente [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20456797/5524514)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode-se utilizar o `find` para encontrar pastas vazias, veja abaixo:

```
find . -type d -empty
```

O `.` indica que a procura será realizada a partir da pasta em que o comando for executado.

Já o `type -d` indica que a produra será feita apenas por diretórios (pastas).

Finalmente o `-empty` indica que a procura será feita por diretórios vazios.